# Change the background colour of the Visual Studio Forms Designer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, background-color

Is it possible to change the background colour of the Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer?

Doesn't appear to be listed in either the `Fonts and Colors`, nor the `Windows Forms Designer` sections of `Tools` > `Options`

Comment: I believe it uses windows system default.

Comment: Do you mean changing the BG color of FORMS? Maybe, check this post  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233653(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Rahul - nope, the Forms Designer Window itself within Visual Studio

Comment: Can you really change color of the Designer Window?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be available in VS2017, even with the plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The designer's background color is hooked to the system's window background color, which you can change from the Control Panel.

[source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/951d87ab-9ab6-4cdf-a531-9bb1aa8a5134)