# Change Backgroundcolor of Visual Studio Design

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I Costumized almost everyting in my Visual Studio,
but i cant figure out how to change the background color of the WinForm Designer.
its white :(

already installed a Theme editor, and i changed almost every value to 444444,
but the Desinger background stays white.

I cant find any info on this subject.

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the background colour of the Visual Studio Forms Designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346130/change-the-background-colour-of-the-visual-studio-forms-designer)