# Change Visual Studio 2012 WPF Forms Designer Background Color

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I, like many developers, like to have dark background and light text - so I use the "Dark" theme on Visual Studio.  However, when developing an application for WPF (which I admittedly do less often than I should), I have noticed that this has an unintended effect of making my controls difficult to read.

Thinking there is an easy solution out there, I tried changing the fonts/colors in VS, to no avail. There does not seem to be a color property for the WPF forms designer background color. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346130/change-the-background-colour-of-the-visual-studio-forms-designer) does not seem to be applicable to either VS 2012 or Windows 7 (not sure which), as I did experiment with the control panel but did not find a suitable setting.

Does anyone know how to make the background a different color (ideally, a medium gray in this case)?  See screenshot.

[image: VS 2013 WPF Designer]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 2012, as I have 2015, but I had a similar issue and found the appropriate settings here in tools->options->Environment->Fonts and Colours and select the XAML Designer:

[image]

Comment: The equivalent setting does not appear in 2013 - perhaps it's just an oversight on the part of MS?